# WooCommerce - Apply coupon of discounts of a given payment method

Tags: woocommerce, payment, coupon

I'm integrating a solution with WooCommerce where a coupon of discount is given depending on the payment method that customer chooses. So, to do it, the coupon needs to be created/applyed in checkout page, when customer is selecting the payment method he wants.
Is it possible? How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 free plugins that allow you to set discount codes based on payment methods:

1. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-added-coupons/ - With over 5K+ active installs, this one seems to be the right choice.
2. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-payment-discounts/ - Although this one has 3K+ active installs, it is specifically meant to give discounts based on payment methods. So this does exactly what you are looking for.

Try out both plugins, preferrably 2nd one first.